# Mouse move on element in protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to hover over a element and later click on it. 
Below is the code

```
 await browser.actions().mouseMove(elm, { x: 200, y: 200 }).perform();
 await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOF(elm2),10000);
 await elm2.click();
```

I also tried without the offset,  like for instance:

```
 await browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).click().perform();
```

However , I could not get the hover effect and click on the element I wanted , i.e elm2 in this case. 
My protractor version is `5.4.1`

Appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

Comment: visibilityOF should be visibilityOf

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo and I used VisibilityOf to make sure if it was a typo error. But no. It seems so weird that inspite of using the protractor helper for `hover` I still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the routines in protractor-test-helper extremely useful and robust. These (and instructions for use and installation) can be found at  [github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper](https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper)

So in your case you would say something like:

```
import { click, hover} from '@hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper/dist';
```

and later

```
await hover(elm, 10000); //hover over item, waiting up to 10 seconds
await click(elm2, 10000, 3); //waits for elm2 to show up, up to 10 seconds, clicks on it, 3 retries
```

But if you just want to look at their hover implementation code for inspiration (not all that different from yours without the offset and with the structure of the three beginning lines), it is at line 55 of https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper/blob/master/dist/actions.js

I know this doesn't tell you exactly how to change what you have, but I hope it gives you at least one (or two) ways to move forward.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the hover helper . I still dont get see the hover effect. Not sure why. It works when I move the mouse over the same element manually. But not with the test script.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I'm stumped. Just so someone else might have a better chance of helping you, can you update to indicate whether the issue is that it does not find elm2 (because of the hover issue) or whether it is the click that fails? (I know the click will fail if it cannot find it, but wondering if perhaps it did find elm2). Could it be the locator for elm2 is no good, and it's not about the hover?

Comment: Well not really. The hovering doesn't work for strange reasons. I am sure I am using the right element. I have verified it multiple times. Its not the click that is failing.

Comment: My scenario is hover on elm1 and once elm2 pops click on it.

Comment: For somereason it elm1 never comes. But the test assumes hovering as done which is not true.

Comment: so an await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm1),10000); or await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm1),10000); fails? Because if so, the hovering is not the issue?! By the way, the helper has a nice waitToBePresent. Also, I wondered is toggling the setting of waitForAngularEnabled might help.